# MKMapView setSelected: animated: not working first time

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, mkmapview

When I call MKMapView method setSelected:animated: on an annotation, it doesn't work. But if I call it next time with a different annotation, it starts working.

Anyone have any ideas what could be possibly wrong?
Thanks

Code (2 relevant methods):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    annotations = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:30] retain];
    for (NSDictionary *entry in entries) {
        double lat = [[entry objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
        double lon = [[entry objectForKey:@"lon"] doubleValue];

        NSString *PLZ = [entry objectForKey:@"PLZ"];
        NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", PLZ.length != 0? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, ", PLZ] : @"", [entry objectForKey:@"Ort"]];
        NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", [entry objectForKey:@"Grund"], [entry objectForKey:@"Zeit"]];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
        coordinate.latitude = lat;
        coordinate.longitude = lon;          
        MyLocation *annotation = [[[MyLocation alloc] initWithName:name address:address coordinate:coordinate] autorelease];
        [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
        [annotations addObject:annotation];
    }

    NSLog(@"LOaded");
    [self zoomToFitMapAnnotations];
}



- (void)showAnnotation:(int)i {
    if (i <= [annotations count]) {
        [mapView setSelectedAnnotations:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[annotations objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }
}
```

The last method, showAnnotation is the one that gets called and an annotation is shown. Once again, it doesn't work with the annotation I call first time. No matter how many times i call it. But if I change the annotation, then it starts working, even with the annotation I called first (hope that makes sense).

Also, this works even the first time:         `[mapView setSelectedAnnotations:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[annotations objectAtIndex:i]]];`

Comment: you might be calling setSelected:animated: from within any of the mapView delegates?

Comment: put your code...so that we can find where did you wrong?

Comment: please check the question. i pasted my relevant code

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be calling that method youself.

According to the `MKAnnotationView` documentation:

> You should not call this method directly. An MKMapView object calls
>   this method in response to user interactions with the annotation.

Instead try Dipen's suggested method (`setSelectedAnnotations`).

Answer (score 1):

Use this may be help you

```
    [mapView1 setSelectedAnnotations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:addAnnotation,nil]];
```

Comment: [mapView1 selectAnnotation:addAnnotation animated:YES];        
this may working